# Grassmann numbers and fermionic strings

Tags: string-theory, fermions, spinors, grassmann-numbers, superspace-formalism

Is it correct that by introducing Grassmann numbers as new directions of spacetime we can make strings behave like fermions (that is, 1/2-spin objects)?

And if so, is it possible to show how that works qualitatively (or with little math)?

Comment: The way you wrote it, no. But the relevant concept (that you are presumably pointing at) is that of [superspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superspace).